# How to create a style within OpenDocument/LibreOffice Writer to get titles on their own page?

Tags: openoffice.org, libreoffice, openoffice-writer, opendocument

I would like to make a style within a LibreOffice text document that formats all my top-level headlines to appear alone on a dedicated page. Actually, I would like to have quite the same as the chapters title pages of the [LibreOffice Writer documentation](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/images/9/96/WG40-WriterGuideLO.odt) but I don't know how to do it.
Any idea how?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can have a look at the [odt document](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/images/9/96/WG40-WriterGuideLO.odt) you cite as example and see how it is done there?

Go to the title page. Select the title - then press F11 to bring up the 'Styles' box.
A special style for these chapter headings has been created called 'OOoHeading 0'. There is a page break before and a page layout style called 'OOoPageStyle'.

[image: Page break proplerties]

See example 'chapters; (around page 185)

A possible scenario: You are writing a book that is divided into chapters. Each chapter starts with a page style called New Chapter. The following pages use the Default page style. At the end of each (except the last) chapter, we return to the New Chapter page style for the first page of the next chapter.
[image: Example chapters]

[image: Modifying the style for heading1]

Implement that in your document.

Comment: I looked at the text, paragraph and page styles and I don't see what is making the title to appear alone on the page.

Comment: There is a page break befor the page with the title. I have added a screen shot to the answer.

Comment: So, is that a manual page break or are the page breaks automatically added with a paragraph style? It seems to be me that these are manual page breaks wand not styles.

Comment: I assure you that I went through the document that I mentioned but I apparently did not see what you are trying to make me guess...

Comment: I have extended the answer.

Comment: Thanks. So if I understand well, that solution requires to manually insert page breaks, isn't it? If yes, then it is not really answering the question because I would like to have a style with some properties that do the job for me. In order, for example, to quickly remove these title pages for my top level headlines and to set title pages for my second or third level headlines WITHOUT manually touching (insert/remove page breaks) to the document structure (the document could be quite long and that would be a nightmare to do).

Comment: As I understand you, you are generating a document with a script. And the script may insert "manual page" breaks as the other information like titles, styles and other thing....

Comment: I guess you are saying that related to a previous question I asked. So yes, I use a script but please don't try to fit the question in your answer: whatever the way the document is generated (manually or dynamically with a script), I want me or somebody (that may not have the skills to modify the script) to be able to change the appearances of the document without manual styling. Do you think there is way to do that?

Comment: Etienne, I have added a screen shot which shows how to modify the style for **heading1**

Comment: That is kind but that still does not answer the question. However, the screen shot your added is what I call automatic styling and is the kind of stuff I am looking for BUT, I would like a page break before AND after which is prevented not only by LibreOffice but by the OpenDocument standard itself...
I guess there is no answer to my question because it is not possible!